# Is "oftimes" a real word?

Tags: vocabulary

I have to do an translation of the text. There is a sentence:

*"In doing so they draw on any, and **oftimes all**, available sourses"*.

It seems like "oftimes" is an abbreviation for "oftentimes" but I'‎m not sure. It may be a grammar mistake as well. 
Searching the Internet, I haven`t found any examples of "oftimes" usage. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a dictionary definition of "ofttimes" (note the spelling)
[Merriam-Webster "ofttimes"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ofttimes)

> chiefly literary
>
> on many occasions : often

*Our books of science, as they improve in accuracy, are in danger of losing the freshness and vigor and readiness to appreciate the real laws of Nature, which is a marked merit in the **ofttimes** false theories of the ancients.— Henry David Thoreau*

Wiktionary shows the etymology of "ofttimes" as "oft + times"; note that "oft" is a word itself, which Merriam-Webster defines as:
: often
 ***oft*** asked questions
 *an **oft** quoted statement*

Neither "oft" nor "ofttimes" is a word for everyday conversation.